# Deploying ASP.NET application with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed an ASP.NET application with AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the following steps:

- Published application to a ZIP file in Visual Studio
- Created Elastic Beanstalk application and environment, using the published ZIP file

All necessary AWS services were provisioned successfully and the application package appears under the Default Website in IIS on the EC2 instance (see screenshot).

[image]

However, I get 403 errors when I try to browse both the Default Website and the application directory (using the "browse" link in the IIS manager).

My question is this: Using Elastic Beanstalk, how do I deploy the application package as a "proper" web site that I can configure to respond to my domain?

I know how to set up a web site and import the application package manually, but I would really like to automate the process with Elastic Beanstalk since we will be deploying to both our staging and production environments frequently.

Comment: It sounds like your application is requiring some sort of authentication. Is there anything enlightening in the logs? (You can get the logs by using the Snapshot Logs feature in the AWS Console or the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio.

Comment: I get the 403 because I am not allowed to browse the directory... so I  think the issue is that the application is not fully deployed, somehow.

Comment: Have to tried browsing from outside the EC2 EB instance? Perhaps the IIS security only allows that type of connection vs localhost