# Deploying Asp.net web application using elastic beanstalk issue

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been having some issues deploying my .net sample application to AWS using elastic beanstalk.

The steps I took was:

Create a .net mvc(5) application in visual studio.

Published it to AWS using elastic beanstalk using the visual studio aws toolkit which happened successfully.

Wait 15 minutes and hit the website. e.g. (http://awstest.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

When I hit the website, I see a blank page with nothing on it, but when I rdp into the virtual machine, and hit `http://localhost/`, it works correctly.

My IIS site setup is very similar to the picture in "[Deploying ASP.NET application with AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629864/deploying-asp-net-application-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk)"

I was wondering if it could be an outbound rule or something I haven't setup? I've searched the web a bit but I haven't been able to find an issue to this unfortunately.

Comment: Fixed issue by changing my app to 4.5 as the server was running .net 4.5 while the app was running 4.5.1.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing my app to 4.5"? I have a problem similar to this where my .Net mvc 5 app built using 4.5.2 is launched "successfully" using AWS toolkit, but when I go to the elastic beanstalk Url, I get connection timeout. Also, when I RDP to Windows Server and check IIS, I also get connection timeout when I go to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I know kokocola self-answered but in case anyone else sees this question: I've seen that when there is an actual .NET exception being thrown from your ASP.NET app. A dll missing a dependency is often a cause. Strange thing is usually the error propagates to the web page with a stack trace, message etc, but sometimes I do just get a blank screen like described in the question. In any case, check the AWS/IIS logs